# Requirement for Transport Stream streaming server

Tags: linux, streaming, live

Heyy Everyone,

We are designing a television module. In the current architecture, we have 2 independent devices, each running linux over Atom processor. We have a requirement to stream live transport stream from one device to another via a network. I tried looking for streaming softwares running on linux, which are capable of live streaming Transport Streams, but could not find any. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

--
Sen

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)
2. [Gstreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net)
3. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
4. [Live555](http://www.live555.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "[Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/)" with "[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)" on "linux" server.
There are many tools for this process. but newly I using srs.

1. [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/)
2. [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)

for send "RTMP" stream please use "[Vmix](https://www.vmix.com/)" or "[OBS](https://obsproject.com/)".

Answer (score 0):

For live streaming, both @dipan-mehta and @fakhredin-gholamizadeh give lots of  open-source softwares, which is stable and widely used.

I want to share about more use scenarios about live streaming, first is about WebRTC. Although WebRTC is design for video conference, but it's also OK to use in live streaming, especially the realtime latency(<1s). Let's take a view from end-to-end latency:

- HLS or DASH: About 3~10s latency, and LLHLS maybe more lower about 3~5s. Note that all the file-based protocols(HLS, HDS, DASH, CMAF, etc) is impossible to get 1s latency.
- RTMP or HTTP-FLV: About 1-3s latency, works quit perfect for most of live streaming use scenarios.
- SRT or WebRTC: About 0.2~1s latency, because they are UDP streaming protocol, and without cumulative latency caused by jitter of network.

> Note that SRT is used in publisher systems, to replace RTMP, it's not support by player(H5) now.

In future, the live streaming protocol maybe QUIC or WebTransport, which is now RFC, and SRS is plan to support it.

As a live streaming server, [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) supports almost all of these protocols:

- RTMP, HLS, HTTP-FLV: Stable.
- WebRTC: Stable.
- DASH, SRT: Experimental.
- HDS: Deprecated.
- LLHLS, CMAF, QUIC, WebTransport: In plan.

> Note: Please see the latest [Features](https://github.com/ossrs/srs#features).

Apart of protocols, it's also important to support DVR and Cluster.